# Question about the divergence theorem in hyperbolic space

Tags: differential-geometry, divergence-theorem

Let   φ: M→H^(n+1) be an n-dimensional compact hypersurface embedding in the hyperbolic space. Denoting by N the interior normal vector to M in H^(n+1). My question is : Is it possible to compute
∫_M〈φ,N〉  dv
In the Euclidean case, M is the boundary of a compact domain Ω of R^(n+1), and by applying the divergence theorem we obtain :
∫_M〈φ,N〉  dv=-(n+1)vol(Ω)
So is it the same for the hyperbolic case?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematics here. Many of your special characters do not show up the same for other people's systems. I don't know what you were intending, but on my machine, ▒ is simply an array of dots.

Comment: This is basically illegible. But start by telling us what $\langle \varphi,N\rangle$ even means in $\Bbb H^{n+1}$.